# How to do a simple routine where you test the link and then download

Tags: javascript

As you can see I'm a beginner in programming, I'm starting little by little! I'm trying to do a little bit of this and that. !! if anyone can help me, I am grateful !!
Where's the error? I'm doing a simple "test and download" routine in javascript

example

```
>"choice
>if online
>download
>else
>mess not found "
```

código

```
<html>
  
<section id="conteudo">
       <select id="opcao">  
        <option>Selecione</option> <tr>
    <option value="209901">JAN/2099</option>
    <option value="202002">FEV/2020</option>
    <option value="202003">MAR/2020</option>
    <option value="202004">ABR/2020</option>
    <option value="202005">MAI/2020</option>
    <option value="202006">JUN/2020</option>
    <option value="202007">JUL/2020</option>
    <option value="202008">AGO/2020</option>
    <option value="202009">SET/2020</option>
    <option value="202010">OUT/2020</option>
    <option value="202011">NOV/2020</option>
    <option value="202012">DEZ/2020</option>
    
    </select>


<button onclick="clickyClick()">Baixar Indice</button> <tbr>



   
<script type='text/javascript'>

        function clickyClick() {
          url = 'http://www.quarta.com.br/downloads/gfip/'+"TF" + document.getElementById("opcao").value+".zip"
         <script url='http://www.quarta.com.br/downloads/gfip/'+"TF" + document.getElementById("opcao").value+".zip" onerror="alert('Indice não disponilizado');" onload="window.open(url, '_blank');" type="text/javascript" ></script>
       
        

</script>
 
    
  
</html>
```

Thanks for all !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: Hi Siva, do you think you could add a little more context to your question, please. I'm not sure what the "test and download" routine is? Could you possibly provide an external link to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: There are script tags that are opened and never closed, also they use "url" instead of "src", and also `'http://www.quarta.com.br/downloads/gfip/'+"TF" + document.getElementById("opcao").value+".zip"` is not a valid source since i'm 99% sure that concatenation and javascript arent available when defining the source

Comment: and what would the right friend be like?